# How to copy InsnList

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, jvm-bytecode

InsnList has no method for copy self.

I tried to iterate list and add each node to new list. But iterating copy of list perform npe

```java
private static InsnList copy(InsnList insnList) {
        InsnList r = new InsnList();

        for (int i = 0; i < insnList.size(); i++)
            r.add(insnList.get(i));

        return r;
}
```

```java
InsnList copy = copy(someList);

for (int i = 0; i < copy.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(copy.get(i));
```

I expected that copy will be, but iterating of copy produce follow error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.InsnList.toArray(InsnList.java:199)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.InsnList.get(InsnList.java:110)
```

Comment: `InsnList` is not thread safe. Is it possible the list is being changed by other thread? Also, why not using `add(InsnList insnList)` instead?

Comment: @KernelMode my app is one-thread. add not relevant because add clear list from argument after adding

Comment: I don't get the exception running this code. can you share the full code?

Answer (score 2):

While I can’t reproduce your specific exception, it seems to be just another symptom of the fundamental problem with your approach. As [the documentation of `AbstractInsnNode`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/tree/AbstractInsnNode.html) states:

> A node that represents a bytecode instruction. *An instruction can appear at most once in at most one `InsnList` at a time.*

So you can’t copy an `InsnList`, at least not by inserting the same nodes into the other list. This is also the reason why the `add(InsnList)` and `insert(InsnList)` methods of `InsnList` remove the nodes from the source list.

When you truly want a copy of the `InsnList`, you also have to create copies of the node objects, which is done easiest via the Visitor API:

```
private static InsnList copy(InsnList insnList) {
    MethodNode mv = new MethodNode();
    insnList.accept(mv);
    return mv.instructions;
}
```

But whenever the task allows it, you should rather use ASM’s Visitor API to write the instructions directly to the target class file rather than creating copies of the instruction list. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57554507/2711488) regarding your actual task.

Comment: I was advised with the following code
https://pastebin.com/qUcbne6L
It work correctly as I look

Comment: Thx for idea with visitors!